# React, update and detect localStorage changes with a custom hook across different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom hook to manage `localStorage` like below:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function useLocalStorage(key, initValue) {

    const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
        const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        if (value !== null) {
            return JSON.parse(value);
        }

        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(initValue));
        return initValue;
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, state);
    }, [key, state])
    
    return [state, setState];
}
```

This custom hook is declared to use the same localstorage key for two or more components in one screen. e,g.

```
const [state, setState] = useLocalStorage('key', false);
```

At this time, since components using `useLocalStorage` want to work according to the state change of `localStorage`, we try to use the state returned by `useLocalStorage` as the second parameter of `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
   foobar()
}, [state]);
```

I expected the `foobar()` function in `useEffect` to work when the "state" changes in all components that declared this `useEffect`. However, `foobar()` only worked for one component out of several components using this same `useEffect`.Why this is happening? How do I get it to work the way I want it to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set up an event listener for storage changes in order to have the updated value. See the code below and the note about storage event:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function useLocalStorage(key, initValue) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (value !== null) {
      return JSON.parse(value);
    }

    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(initValue));
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage"));
    return initValue;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, state);
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage"));
  }, [key, state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const listenStorageChange = () => {
      setState(() => {
        const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        if (value !== null) {
          return JSON.parse(value);
        }

        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(initValue));
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage"));
        return initValue;
      });
    };
    window.addEventListener("storage", listenStorageChange);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("storage", listenStorageChange);
  }, []);

  return [state, setState];
}
```

You might wonder why this `dispatchEvent` is used. Well here is what MDN says about [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event):

> The `storage` event of the `Window` interface fires when a storage area (`localStorage`) has been modified in the context of `another document`.

This `dispatchEvent` is needed as we need to listen to changes in the same document as well.

Comment: do you mean to remove the storage listener in the cleanup function? e.g. I expected to see `return () => window.removeEventListener("storage", listenStorageChange)`

Comment: In addition to your answer, I solved the problem by adding `window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage");` after `localStorage.setItem(key, state);`.

It seems that the storage event is not triggered by changes in localStorage that occur in the same tab.

Comment: Thank you so much @HATENA for letting me know that. I added that in the answer.