# How to link button from one page to do something on other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have button ,,Submit" on register page, and imported another page to display, and i need to use that button from register page to submit things on that imported one, how you see in my code bellow, i "open these pages" in my main register page so its same page and its not ....

[Thats how that main register page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ET7.png)

How you see, button on main page, and that form linked from different one
My main gole is to make that button disabled if form is not filled right . . i have done everything on that from, but i dont know how to link that button to it

> Main Register Page:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import RegisterS1 from "./registerS1";
import RegisterS2 from "./registerS2";
import RegisterS3 from "./registerS3";
import RegisterS4 from "./registerS4";
import RegisterS5 from "./registerS5";
import RegisterS6 from "./registerS6";
import RegisterS7 from "./registerS7";
import './register.css';

    return (
      <>
        <div>
            {activeStep == 1 && <Button onClick={handleNext}>Skip</Button>}
            {activeStep > 0 && <Button onClick={handleBack}>Back</Button>}
            {activeStep === 0 && <RegisterS1 />}
            {activeStep === 1 && <RegisterS2 />}
            {activeStep === 2 && <RegisterS3 />}
            {activeStep === 3 && <RegisterS4 />}
            {activeStep === 4 && <RegisterS5 />}
            {activeStep === 5 && <RegisterS6 />}
            {activeStep === 6 && <RegisterS7 />}
            <div>
            <Button
              style={{
                position: "relative", 
                marginLeft: "16vw",
                marginTop: "2vh",
              }}
              disabled={localStorage.registerForm.includes("false")}
              onClick={handleNext} 
              size="large" 
              variant="contained" 
              endIcon={<NavigateNextIcon />}
            >Submit</Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
};
```

> RegisterS1

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

const FIRSTNAME_REGEX = /^[A-ZĽŠČŤŽ][a-zľščťžýáíéúň]{1,23}$/;
const LASTNAME_REGEX = /^[A-ZĽŠČŤŽ][a-zľščťžýáíéúň]{1,23}$/;
const USERNAME_REGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,23}$/;
const EMAIL_REGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9](?=.*[@]).{5,30}$/;
const PWD_REGEX = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,24}$/;


export default function RegisterS1() {

  const [firstname, setFirstname] = useState("");
  const [validFirstname, setValidFirstname] = useState(false);

  const [lastname, setLastname] = useState("");
  const [validLastname, setValidLastname] = useState(false);

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [validUsername, setValidUsername] = useState(false);

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [validEmail, setValidEmail] = useState(false);

  const [pwd, setPwd] = useState("");
  const [validPwd, setValidPwd] = useState(false);

  const [matchPwd, setMatchPwd] = useState("");
  const [validMatch, setValidMatch] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(localStorage.registerForm === undefined) {
      var registerForm = ["", "", "", "", "", ""];
      localStorage.registerForm = JSON.stringify(registerForm);
      setFirstname(registerForm[0]);
      setLastname(registerForm[1]);
      setUsername(registerForm[2]);
      setEmail(registerForm[3]);
      setPwd(registerForm[4]);
      setMatchPwd(registerForm[5]);
    } else {
      var registerForm = (JSON.parse(localStorage.registerForm));
      setFirstname(registerForm[0]);
      setLastname(registerForm[1]);
      setUsername(registerForm[2]);
      setEmail(registerForm[3]);
      setPwd(registerForm[4]);
      setMatchPwd(registerForm[5]);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValidFirstname(FIRSTNAME_REGEX.test(firstname));
  }, [firstname]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValidLastname(LASTNAME_REGEX.test(lastname));
  }, [lastname]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValidUsername(USERNAME_REGEX.test(username));
  }, [username]);

  useEffect(() => {
      setValidEmail(EMAIL_REGEX.test(email));
  }, [email]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValidPwd(PWD_REGEX.test(pwd));
    setValidMatch(pwd === matchPwd);
  }, [pwd, matchPwd]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let registerForm = [firstname, lastname, username, email, pwd, matchPwd];
    const v1 = FIRSTNAME_REGEX.test(firstname);
    const v2 = LASTNAME_REGEX.test(lastname);
    const v3 = USERNAME_REGEX.test(username);
    const v4 = EMAIL_REGEX.test(email);
    const v5 = PWD_REGEX.test(pwd);
    if (!v1 || !v2 || !v3 || !v4 || !v5 || pwd != matchPwd) {
      var setSuccess = false;
    } else { var setSuccess = true; };
    registerForm.push(setSuccess)
    localStorage.registerForm = JSON.stringify(registerForm);
  }, [firstname, lastname, username, email, pwd, matchPwd]);

  return(
    <>
      <div>
       <Box
        component="form"
        sx={{'& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },}}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
       >
       <div>
         <TextField
           focused
           error={!validFirstname && firstname}
           id="first-name"
           type="text"
           label="First Name"
           variant="filled"
           color={!firstname ? "" : validFirstname ? "success" : ""}
           onChange={(e) => setFirstname(e.target.value)}
           value={firstname}
           helperText={!firstname ? "" : !validFirstname ? "Must begin with a capital letter. Only Letters are allowed." : ""}
           style={{marginLeft: "4vw", marginTop: "7vh", width: '15vw'}}
         />
         <TextField
           focused
           error={!validLastname && lastname}
           id="last-name"
           type="text"
           label="Last Name"
           variant="filled"
           color={!lastname ? "" : validLastname ? "success" : ""}
           onChange={(e) => setLastname(e.target.value)}
           value={lastname}
           helperText={!lastname ? "" : !validLastname ? "Must begin with a capital letter. Only Letters are allowed." : ""}
           style={{marginTop: "7vh", width: '15vw'}}
         />
       </div>
       <div>
       <TextField
           focused
           fullWidth
           error={!validUsername && username}
           id="username"
           type="text"
           label="Username"
           variant="filled"
           color={!username ? "" : validUsername ? "success" : ""}
           onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
           value={username}
           helperText={!username ? "" : !validUsername ? "Incorrect entry." : ""}
           style={{marginLeft: "4vw", marginTop: "1vh", width: '15vw'}}
         />
         <TextField
           focused
           fullWidth
           error={!validEmail && email}
           id="email"
           type="text"
           label="Email"
           variant="filled"
           color={!email ? "" : validEmail ? "success" : ""}
           onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
           value={email}
           helperText={!email ? "" : !validEmail ? "Incorrect entry, only gmail.com is allowed." : ""}
           style={{marginTop: "1vh", width: '15vw'}}
         />
       </div>
       <div>
         <TextField
           focused
           fullWidth
           error={!validPwd && pwd}
           id="password"
           type="password"
           label="Password"
           variant="filled"
           color={!pwd ? "" : validPwd ? "success" : ""}
           onChange={(e) => setPwd(e.target.value)}
           value={pwd}
           helperText={!pwd ? "" : !validPwd ? "Must contain 8 to 24 characters. Must include uppercase and lowercase letters, and a number. All special characters are allowed." : ""}
           style={{marginLeft: "4vw", marginTop: "1vh", width: '31vw'}}
         />
       </div>
       <div>
         <TextField
           focused 
           fullWidth
           error={!validMatch && matchPwd || !validPwd && matchPwd}
           id="confirm_password"
           type="password"
           label="Confirm Password"
           variant="filled"
           color={!matchPwd ? "" : validPwd && validMatch ? "success" : ""}
           onChange={(e) => setMatchPwd(e.target.value)}
           value={matchPwd}
           helperText={!matchPwd ? "" : !validMatch ? "Password not Match!" : validPwd ? "" : "Weak Password"}
           style={{marginLeft: "4vw", marginTop: "1vh", width: '31vw'}}
         />
       </div>
       </Box>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

i tryed to save button click to local storage, but not working

Comment: To clarify, you're asking how to disable/enable the submit button based on the state of your validations right?

Comment: yes, if u look at ... there are no lines .... RegisterS1 and one useEffect have "v1", "v2", "v3" and etc . . . here im adding true or false to end in local store, but im not able to call it in main register, i tryed disabled={localStorage.registerForm.includes("false")} but not worked, well it worked, but only after page refresh

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72389111/react-update-and-detect-localstorage-changes-with-a-custom-hook-across-differen I think it will help your usecase

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set that hooks on main register page and send them as a prop to other pages and basically add a style to it with chaining all these condition hooks to prevent click/tab. I don't know very well but if you can chain that conditions with "pointerEvents" property's value and if they're all true conditionally make "unset" and if they aren't make "none" that. I think it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by this

```
<Button
  style={{
    position: "relative", 
    marginLeft: "16vw",
    marginTop: "2vh",
    }}
  onClick={handleNext} 
  size="large" 
  variant="contained" 
  endIcon={<NavigateNextIcon />}
  >Submit</Button>
```

i let that button disabled = false (by default) and make this

```
const handleNext = () => {
    if(localStorage.registerForm.includes("false")) {
      console.log("Form is WRONG!")
    } else {
      const npp = activeStep + 1;
      setActiveStep(npp);
      handleClick();
    }
  };
```

I realized that i have saved true or false in local store if form is filled right and used that to test is when button is pressed, so i just do like that loading animation after click and if form is wrong, just show error message like "Hey, your inputs are not correct" or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at: [React, update and detect localStorage changes with a custom hook across different components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72389111/react-update-and-detect-localstorage-changes-with-a-custom-hook-across-differen)

Here is an explanation to create a custom hook which will fire when a value is updated in localstorage.

Alternatively you can skip using local storage all together and store the state inside a hook on the top level component, for example as explained here: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/managing-state#sharing-state-between-components.

The goal of a using a hook is to fire an event which will cause the component to rerender itself.

State management in React.js has always been hard. It wasn't originally designed as part of the React library and because of this you can find about a thousand different solutions to this problem. It is use full to do some research on all the options, their pros and cons if you want to put your components into a production environment. For example at my company we use https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand at the moment to manage our state between components.